# Algebraic derivation to show the limiting probability of a continuous time markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

**Problem:**

> Customers arrive at a single-server queue in accordance with a Poisson
> process having rate $\lambda$. However, an arrival that finds $n$
> customers already in the system will only join the system with
> probability $1 /(n+1)$. That is, with probability $n /(n+1)$ such an
> arrival will not join the system. Show that the limiting distribution
> of the number of customers in the system is Poisson with mean $\lambda
>  / \mu$. Assume that the service distribution is exponential with rate
> $\mu$.

**My attempt:**

I recognized that this is a birth and death process and therefore should solve the balance equations.

For $i=0$,
$$
\lambda_0 P_0=\mu_1 P_1 .
$$
For every $i>0$,
$$
\left(\lambda_i+\mu_i\right) P_i=\mu_{i+1} P_{i+1}+\lambda_{i-1} P_{i-1} .
$$

I understand that I need to find an expression for $P_i$. From the context of the problem I see that $\lambda_i = \frac{1}{i+1}$ and $\mu_i = \mu$

**Problem 1**

In the answer manual the folling statement is made:

$$
\text { It follows from the first } i-1 \text { equations that } P_i=\lambda /(i \mu) P_{i-1} \text { for } i \geq 1
$$

- Question 1: How can I derive this expression from the balancing equations?

**Problem 2**

The final solutions is:

$$
P_i=\frac{(\lambda / \mu)^i}{i !} P_0, \quad \text { for } i \geq 1
$$

The task was to show that the limiting distribution is poisson distributed. In the final answer I see that the expression looks like a Poisson distribution, but I miss the exponential term.

- Question 2: Why is the final expression considered Poisson distributed, but there is no exponential term as in the original Poisson distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a birth and death process and therefore should solve the balance equations.

For $i=0$,
$$
\lambda_0 P_0=\mu_1 P_1 .
$$
For every $i>0$, the following flow balance equations hold if you consider pairs of neighboring states (flow in=flow out for every pair of neighbors)
$$
\lambda_i P_i=\mu_{i+1} P_{i+1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lambda_i/\mu_{i+1} P_i= P_{i+1}
$$
and
$$
\lambda/((i+1)\mu) P_{i-1}= P_{i}
$$

Indeed,  $\lambda_i = \frac{1}{i+1}$ and $\mu_i = \mu$

**Problem 1**

$$
\text { It follows from the first } i-1 \text { equations that } P_i=\lambda /(i \mu) P_{i-1} \text { for } i \geq 1
$$

- Question 1: How can I derive this expression from the balancing equations?

This should be clear from the above argument.

**Problem 2**

The final solutions is:

$$
P_i=\frac{(\lambda / \mu)^i}{i !} P_0, \quad \text { for } i \geq 1
$$

To get the above expression, you use the fact that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n! = e^x$$

- Question 2: Why is the final expression considered Poisson distributed, but there is no exponential term as in the original Poisson distribution?

$$
\sum P_i=1= P_0 \sum\frac{(\lambda / \mu)^i}{i !}  
$$

Therefore,

$$P_0=e^{-\lambda/\mu}$$

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explaination